# Is there a way to use a midi file like a list where each element is a note - and play them individually?

Tags: python, midi

I'm trying to play a piano MIDI file with Python note by note. Is there a way to represent a MIDI file as a list of notes ? And can I play each one on my computer sound output ?

Ideally it would look like this:

```py
song = '/pathto/file.mid'

play(song[0])   #would play the first note of file.mid

play(song[n])   #would play the note n of file.mid
```

Comment: WHy downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for the module called `winsound`

This would produce a beep sound:

```py
import winsound
winsound.Beep(1500, 1000)
```

The first argument in `winsound.Beep` is the frequency, then the second is how 
long the sound should be in milliseconds.

Look here for the frequency of the notes on the piano:
http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-notenames.htm

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Also, you can play some music files with winsound, although I don't know how. Here is reference. https://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html